# Gatsby: 404 page thrown on browser navigation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, hyperlink, navigation, gatsby

**Gatsby v3** is throwing a **404 page** if I navigate to a route with browser buttons instead of clicking on a link. How can I fix this issue?

#### Steps to Reproduce

1. Start the Gatsby project with `gatsby develop` command.
2. Navigate from index page to about page by clicking on link.
3. Refresh the browser on about page.
4. Click on browser's back navigation.
5. For an unknown reason index page throws 404 page instead.

#### GIF

You may refer to the GIF attached below for better clarity.

[image: GIF for 404 page error in Gatsby]

#### Index Page: `src/pages/index.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const IndexPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>Index Page</h1>
      <Link to="/about">About Me</Link>
    </main>
  );
};

export default IndexPage;
```

#### About Page: `src/pages/about.js`

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'gatsby';

const AboutPage = () => {
  return (
    <main>
      <h1>About Page</h1>
      <Link to="/">Back To Home</Link>
    </main>
  );
};

export default AboutPage;
```

#### Package.json

```json
{
  "name": "my-gatsby-site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "description": "My Gatsby Site",
  "keywords": [
    "gatsby"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "gatsby develop",
    "start": "gatsby develop",
    "build": "gatsby build",
    "serve": "gatsby serve",
    "clean": "gatsby clean"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "gatsby": "^3.6.2",
    "gatsby-plugin-gatsby-cloud": "^2.8.1",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It only happens in development mode. After build it works as should.

However you can use this 'dirty' fix:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js

exports.onInitialClientRender = () => {
  // dirty fix for missing popstate listener
  const GATSBY_NAVIGATE = window.___navigate || {}

  window.addEventListener('popstate', () =>
    GATSBY_NAVIGATE(window.location.pathname, { replace: true })
  )
}
```

Source: https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/7261#issuecomment-414304749

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).